# Infrequent data-corrupting bug when writing "values "

Tags: bug, unicode, posting

Stack Exchange suffers from some [zero-width space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-width_space) characters being inserted in the post data quite infrequently when the text *"values "* (with a trailing space) is being used.

For people not too familiar with invisible unicode characters, you may copy-paste the content from the below examples to an online editor like the green textarea from https://r12a.github.io/app-conversion/ and tap **Convert**, then you'll discover the hidden single or double spaces `&#x200B;`/`\u{200B}`/`U+200B` that were inserted.

Now, this bug doesn't happen all the time... from my analysis, it happens maybe 1 time out of 500 usages of text *"values "*. But with the amount of posts on the Stack Exchange network, I was easily able to find with [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com) thousands of occurrences of this issue across Stack Exchange.

Demonstration that the bug, when it kicks in, affects both the title and the body of the post:

- [recover the values ​starting with group_slide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011035/recover-the-values-starting-with-group-slide)

Demonstration that it also affects Mathematics (and not just Stack Overflow):

- [Find the possible values ​for D](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2819039/find-the-possible-values-for-d)

Demonstration that to trigger the bug, the pattern doesn't require a space before "values " (but requires one after):

- [eigenvalues ​​and eigenvectors](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884708/eigenvalues-and-eigenvectors)

Demonstration that it doesn't affect all posts, by comparing some recent posts created on the same day (Oct 26, 2018):

- [q/53017172](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53017172/) is unaffected
- [q/53016816](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53016816/) has the bug
- [q/53016580](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53016580/) is unaffected
- [q/53011035](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53011035/) has the bug

Potentially oldest Stack Overflow post affected:

- [How to access to a NSArray, after extract values ​​from a json file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6276829/how-to-access-to-a-nsarray-after-extract-values-from-a-json-file) from 2011-06-08 09:42:07Z

Which could mean that the bug wasn't there in 2008/2009/2010.

Comment: You apparently have used SEDE to identify these posts. Any reason for not sharing your SEDE query but just linking to the SEDE home page?

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth because I used an old query that wasn't targetting this specific issue at all: I just happened to figure out after many months using it that there was an abnormal frequency of the word "values": https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/712284/unicode-title

Comment: I just hope this doesn't qualify as a pluralization bug...

Comment: You would almost expect it to be related to the client used, either a certain webbrowser or maybe one the apps, although the latter seems unlikely given the elaborate questions that expose said bug.